# Scanner double value- InputMismatchException

Tags: java

I am trying to prompt user to enter x coordinate but when I write a decimal number such as 2.1 as an input this is caused a problem .How can I fix the problem?

```
     import java.util.Scanner;

     public class TwoRetangles{

     public static void main(String[]args){

     Scanner input=new Scanner(System.in);

      System.out.print("Enter the center x coordinate of retangle = ");

      double x1=input.nextDouble();

      }
}
```

--------------------Configuration: --------------------

```
      Enter the center x coordinate of retangle = 2.1

     Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException

     at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:909)

     at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1530)

     at java.util.Scanner.nextDouble(Scanner.java:2456)

     at TwoRetangles.main(TwoRetangles.java:6)

     Process completed.
```

Comment: you want a decimal or a double?

Answer (score 4):

Your code works for me.. Scanner is tied to your system settings I believe, so if its not for US you couldn't use a decimal like 2.1.

If that is the case, do

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in).useLocale(Locale.US);
```

You would need to import java.util.*;

Answer (score 0):

There is no error.It is working fine in my system.Make sure you compiled it right.It is accepting the value.I tried this code and it is printing 2.1:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class TwoRetangles{

   public static void main(String[]args){

   Scanner input=new Scanner(System.in);

   System.out.print("Enter the center x coordinate of retangle = ");

   double x1=input.nextDouble();

   System.out.print(x1);

      }
}
```